# Having same protractor version in package.json installing different chrome driver versions?

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am confused with the protractor versions and how exactly it works.
so there are two different node projects which I have created, and I am using protractor versions  `"protractor": "~5.4.0"` in both of my projects.

**When I am trying to run command `npm run e2e` one project is installing chrome driver version 2.46**

`[15:12:36] I/downloader - curl -o/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.46.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[15:12:36] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.46.zip
[15:12:36] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.46
[15:12:36] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:12:36] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...`

`{
  "name": "solutions-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:deployment": "ng test --watch=false --no-progress --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
 "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular-web-storage": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.5",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-data-provider": "~2.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "tiny-date-picker": "^3.2.8",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }`

**Another project is installing chrome driver version _75.0.3770.140**

`[14:40:30] I/config_source - curl -o/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[14:40:30] I/downloader - curl -o/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.90/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[14:40:31] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip
[14:40:31] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140
[14:40:31] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:40:31] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...`

`{
  "name": "web-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": ">=3.1.11",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}`

how is this possible when I am giving the same protractor version?
can someone help me to understand the process and help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: can you add both `package.json` files.

Comment: added package.json files for both projects

Comment: The only way can ensure install same version of protractor is to change dependency to `"protractor": "5.4.0",` .  `~` can't keep version stick at 5.4.0.  And remove package-lock.json after change dependency, then execute `npm install` 
 and `ng e2e` again.

Answer (score 0):

### An old version of webdriver-manager

This means that you have a webdriver-manager node module in the first project that is old. Downloading chromedriver 2.46 no longer works with the latest releases of Chrome.

Protractor ~5.4.x package.json dependency requires webdriver-manager ^12.x.x. This means that it will download any minor version update. So for a newer install of your test, you'll pull down a newer version of webdriver-manager. These later versions have fixes regarding Chrome browser major versions. Right now the latest should be pulling down version 76 of ChromeDriver.

### Trying to download the right version of ChromeDriver

Let's say you still need version 2.46 of chromedriver because you are still running Chrome version 73 (I think that was the version of Chrome it supported), then you could get it with `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.46`. Similarly, if you need version 75, you could download a specific version from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com. So you could run `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 75.0.3770.90` and that will download that specific version.

### Will this get better?

Yes. There are some fixes but that support is not happening for the current webdriver-manager version 12. There are breaking changes that will soon be adopted by Protractor 6...when it comes out (eventually).